# Problem with Routes using Devise and Omniauth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, devise, omniauth

I am trying to get OAuth and Devise working together but I get `Controller::RoutingError (No route matches "/users/auth/facebook/callback"):` when trying to auth via Facebook.

Weirdly, the problem doesn't happen with Google Apps. (same callback route).

Any ideas?

callback_controller:

```
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController

  def facebook
    # You need to implement the method below in your model
    @user = User.find_for_facebook_oauth(env["omniauth.auth"], current_user)

    if @user.persisted?
      flash[:notice] = I18n.t "devise.omniauth_callbacks.success", :kind => "Facebook"
      sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication
    else
      session["devise.facebook_data"] = env["omniauth.auth"]
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
  end

  def google_apps
    @user = User.find_for_google_apps_oauth(env["omniauth.auth"], current_user)

    if @user.persisted?
      flash[:notice] = I18n.t "devise.omniauth_callbacks.success", :kind => "Google Apps"
      sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication
    else
      session["devise.google_apps_data"] = env["omniauth.auth"]
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
  end

  def passthru
    render :file => "#{Rails.root}/public/404.html", :status => 404, :layout => false
  end

end
```

routes.rb:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks" } do
  get '/users/auth/:provider' => 'users/omniauth_callbacks#passthru'
end
```

Why would the `:provider => "facebook"` trigger a RoutingError, but not `:provider => "google_apps"`?

Comment: is your file in `app/controllers/users/omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb?`

Comment: Yup!  And like I said - The Google one works fine - its just when using Facebook.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found it:

in the devise user model, i had the module: `:omniauth_providers => [:facebook, :openid, :google_apps]` added which (apparently) doesn't do what I thought it did.  I removed the line and now all my auth logic works properly once again.