# How do I setup omniauth-facebook on an already existing omniauth and devise rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, facebook-graph-api, omniauth

So, I followed the instructions as mentioned here http://railscasts.com/episodes/235-devise-and-omniauth-revised and successfully setup the the sign in and sign up with twitter option. Now I am trying to setup facebook. Using the `gem 'omniauth-facebook'`. After installing it. I then added to `/config/initializers/devise.rb` file

```
config.omniauth :facebook, ENV["FB_APP_ID"], ENV["FB_SECRET_ID"]
```

Now, when I try to sign in with facebook. I get the error -

```
ArgumentError in OmniauthCallbacksController#facebook

wrong number of arguments(3 for 2)
```

I was doubting an error might show up. But not sure how to fix it.

My controller and user model are same as mentioned here - http://railscasts.com/episodes/235-devise-and-omniauth-revised

What am i missing?

UPDATE: I did change this in the user.rb model file

instead of
`alias_method :twitter, :all`
I made it 
`alias_method :twitter, :facebook :all`

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :facebook, 'FB_APP_ID', 'FB_SECRET_ID'
```

but i didn't use devise, so just try to remove the `ENV` .

Also read here about all the options and some fails you may encounter:

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth%3a-Overview

Comment: I got it with `ENV`. I wasnt performing it through the `config.middleware` method and Omnauth build as you did above. Got it working now. thanks

Comment: yes but i am still confsued, as to how do i handle both the method (for twitter and facebook together)?

Comment: because now i get `No route matches [GET] "/users/auth/facebook/callback"`

Comment: Oh, okay, sorry i thought you got it all covered. look here for that problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6339532/problem-with-routes-using-devise-and-omniauth

Comment: I didn't do it with devise so i don't know the exact differences from doing it from scratch

Comment: i actually figured it out. I just had to do a `require "omniauth-facebook"` and then rest all was figured out. Thanks